# API Platform - Dev - all requests return empty result

Tags: api-platform.com

I have set up API platform and am trying to test the API using curl, eg.

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/authentication_token -d '{"email":"test@test.com","password":"the_new_password"}'`

`curl http://localhost/docs`

I am getting no response from the server, always blank.

Answer (score 0):

Requests needed to be HTTPS, as it seems HTTP requests are simply thrown away / ignored. Add the `-k` flag since the certificate will be self signed and CURL will error out.

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost/authentication_token -d '{"email":"test@test.com","password":"the_new_password"}' -k`

`curl https://localhost/docs -k`